# Javascript Error on window.navigate

Tags: javascript, web-applications

The code for the pages is quite complex so hopefully you'll be able to get what's happen from these basics. Before I start the Error is and relates to the line

```
Unspecified error. Line 493. window.navigate("...");
```

The page has a countdown timer which when it reaches 0 executes the above window.navigate. Also on the page is a check that asks if the they want to navigate away when unloading the page.

The error occurs when the timer executes the navigate then the check loads the pop-up box. If you click cancel as to not navigate away then the error is thrown.

The two actions have been written in individually on are used on other pages of the application though the page in question is the only time the two will meet.

Has anyone got any ideas on how I could get around this problem.

If you need any more information just ask.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What king of check are you using to ask if the user wants to stay on the page?
Have you tried (if you aren't already) using `window.location.href = "url";` instead of `window.navigate("url")`?
And maybe using this (if you aren't already) to check if the user wants to stay on the site:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "You are about to leave this page, OK?";
};
```

Else there just might be some other error in the code, as normally this code works. I hope this is what you were looking for.